# How to check what kind of message one module is receiving from another module?

Tags: omnet++

I am new to using Omnet++. So I have two modules in my network - source and sink. My sink node sends two kinds of messages to the sensor node. I use the send() function for that. Now how do I check on my sensor node's side what type of message it has received?

Answer (score 2):

One may use `dynamic_cast` to determine if received message is of a specific type.
Let's assume that a module expects two types of packets: `Request` and `Ack`. The following piece of code shows how to determine the type of the message.

```
void YourModule::handleMessage(cMessage * msg) {
  Request * req = dynamic_cast<Request*>(msg);
  if (req != nullptr) {
     // req is of Request type

  } else {
    Ack* ack = dynamic_cast<Ack*>(msg);
    if (ack != nullptr) {
      // ack is of Ack type
  }
}
```